# Update the Apache Kafka Spring boot solution to connect with Confluent Cloud Kafka?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I have a Java Spring Boot application that connects with Apache Kafka

**KafkaController.java**

```
package com.demo.controllers;

import com.demo.engine.Producer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/kafka")
public class KafkaController {

    private final Producer producer;

    @Autowired
    KafkaController(Producer producer) {
        this.producer = producer;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/publish")
    public void sendMessageToKafkaTopic(@RequestParam("message") String message) {
        this.producer.sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

**Consumer.java**

```
package com.demo.engine;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;

@Service
public class Consumer {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "users", groupId = "group_id")
    public void consume(String message) throws IOException {
        logger.info(String.format("#### -> Consumed message -> %s", message));
    }
}
```

**Producer.java**

```
package com.demo.engine;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Producer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);
    private static final String TOPIC = "users";

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        logger.info(String.format("#### -> Producing message -> %s", message));
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, message);
    }
}
```

**SpringBootWithKafkaApplication.java**

```
package com.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWithKafkaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWithKafkaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 9000
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      group-id: group_id
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

it works fine with the local kafka instance and I have create a Confluent cloud account and created a  Kafka topic

[image]

I understood that I have to use the below configuration for Confluent Cloud Kafka as shown below

```
# Kafka
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap.servers=pkc-epwny.eastus.azure.confluent.cloud:9092
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule   required username='{{ CLUSTER_API_KEY }}'   password='{{ CLUSTER_API_SECRET }}';
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
# Confluent Cloud Schema Registry
spring.kafka.properties.basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO
spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info={{ SR_API_KEY }}:{{ SR_API_SECRET }}
spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url=https://{{ SR_ENDPOINT }}
```

however not sure where to add the above configuration and what kind of code change is required.

Comment: You could simply use `application.properties` instead of `application.yaml`, then you wouldn't need to change much

Comment: Where can I find the SR_ENDPOINT? I haven't defined any schema.

Comment: Then remove the schema registry properties. They aren't required. However, using a schema is certainly a good idea compared to a raw string or unknown JSON blobs

Comment: Thank you, I don't know what am I missing, it is not working for me. Do you have any reference/sample application?

Comment: There should be a few Spring examples in Confluent's github repos, but I don't have specific links